# Commerce: How can I save a custom SKU from a plugin?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I have a plugin that is listening to the `onSaveProduct` event.

In my product settings, in the "Automatic SKU Format" field I have:

```
{product.title}
```

That way I am always working the main product title.

For the SKU, I want to only use the first initial of each word - so I am doing this from my plugin:

```
...
$default_sku = $event->params['product']->defaultVariant->sku;
$expr = '/(?<=\s|^)[a-z]/i';

preg_match_all($expr, $default_sku, $matches);

$sku = strtoupper(implode('', $matches[0]));

...

error_log((craft()->config->get('devMode')) ? 'SKU: ' . $sku : '');
```

Let's say I have "My Super Product" as the title. The above is generating this: **MSP**

Perfect!

But, now I'm not sure how to go *back* and re-save the product.

Do I need to re-find the product and then set the `defaultSku` and then re-save it? Not sure how to proceed.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this the usual way of setting entry fields in a plugin I think:

```
        $product->setContentFromPost(array(
            'sku' => $sku,
        );
        craft()->commerce_products->saveProduct($product);
```

(Alternatively, you could listen to `onBeforeSaveProduct` -  https://craftcommerce.com/docs/events-reference#commerce_products.onbeforesaveproduct - and since the product will be saved after that anyway you could probably leave out the call to `saveProduct` in that case)

I don't think I've tried it with products but it certainly works with orders for much the same sort of thing.